# Django WeekArchiveView: Have urls start at 1

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views

I use the Django "WeekArchiveView" to display instances of my Appointment model by week.
The View looks like this:

```
class AppointmentWeekArchiveView(WeekArchiveView):
    queryset = Appointment.objects.all().order_by('start_date')
    date_field = "start_date"
    make_object_list = True
    allow_future = True
    allow_empty = True
    week_format = '%W'
```

I set the week_format to have weeks start on Monday.
The corresponding entry in urls.py looks like this:

```
url(r'^(?P<year>\d{4})/week/(?P<week>\d+)$',
    views.AppointmentWeekArchiveView.as_view(),
    name="appointment_week")
```

All works well except for one problem: The first week of a year is located at /2013/week/0, which I find confusing in this context.

Is there a way to have them start at 1, so that I have consistency between the url of the week and the output of, e.g. `{{ week | date:'W' }}` ?

I have not found any hints regarding this behavior in the documentation.

I just realized, that for some other years (e.g. 2012) the urls actually match the week-number. I tried implementing next/previous week links like the following:

```
{% url 'appointments:appointment_week' previous_week|date:'Y' previous_week|date:'W' %}
```

and

```
{% url 'appointments:appointment_week' next_week|date:'Y' next_week|date:'W' %}
```

These also fail for 2013 but work for e.g. 2012.
The `previous_week` and `next_week` variables are provided by the View class and are pointing to the (correct) first day of the next/previous week.

Answer (score 1):

The views use [`strptime`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) to convert a string constructed from the appropriate elements into a Python date, and `strptime`'s week parsing uses 0 to represent days that fall before the first start of the week day (Sunday or Monday depending on whether you're using `%U` or `%W`) in a given year. To get Jan 1, 2003 from a week string, you have to give it `'0'`. So I don't think there will be a totally simple way to do this.

These are untested, and I wouldn't really recommend them, but you might be able to customize your `get_dated_items` method on your view to use something other than `strptime` to construct the actual date ranges to be covered by the view. Or - and this is pretty ugly - customize `get_week` to check `self.year` to see if its first day falls on the week start date, and if not to return a string containing the captured week number minus one.

In both cases you'd have to pay attention to how you generate your URLs as well. What's currently generating `/2013/week/0`?

Comment: What do you mean by what is generating /2013/week/0 ?
week/0 returns the correct view for the first week of 2013, starting at Dec. 31, 2012, which is correct.

Comment: I mean that somewhere you have to be generating URLs to point to your view. Typically with `{% url ... %}` or `reverse`.

Comment: At the moment, I only have a hardlink to a specific week. Later it should always point to the current week.
I did, however, try to implement a next/ previous week link in the view. I updated the question accordingly.